# Filter array of Any based on variable

Tags: swift, filter, anyobject

I have an array of type `Any` in that array there are two different types, `Person` and `SportsMan` both these has a value called `rank`. I want to sort my array based on the rank. Here is how I have done it today and it works:

```
self.persons.sort {
    let a = ($0 as AnyObject) as? Person
    let b = ($0 as AnyObject) as? SportsMan
    let l = a?.rank ?? b?.rank

    let c = ($1 as AnyObject) as? Person
    let d = ($1 as AnyObject) as? SportsMan
    let r = c?.rank ?? d?.rank
    return l! < r!
}
```

I´m feeling a bit unsure because of the `!` in `l! < r!`. Is this a good way to solve this or is it any built in function to use for this?

Comment: Better way: make `Person` and `SportsMan` have a common base class / protocol which has the `rank` property. Then do not use `[Any]` but `[YourBaseClass]`.

Comment: Why are you casting via `AnyObject`? If `Person` and `SportsMan` have common functionality – use a protocol (and have the array of that protocol).

Comment: @luk2302 I'll second what you've said, a protocol would certainly work.

Comment: @luk2302, do you mind write an example of how to do this?

Comment: Does `SportsMan` inherit from `Person`?

Comment: @Alexander, no it does not it was just some example names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a protocol such as `Rankable`, and make `Person` and `SportsMan` conform to it.

```
protocol Rankable {
    var rank: Int { get }
}
```

Then make your array into an `[Rankable]` (a.k.a. `Array<Rankable>`) rather than `[Any]`, and sort it like so:

```
self.persons.sort{ $0.rank < $1.rank }
```

Comment: Where should I add that protocol and I suspect that I need to remove the rank property from Person and SportsMan and use Person: Rankable and use the rank inside that property instead or?

Comment: The existing `rank` property of `Person` and `SportsMan` can fulfill the protocol's requirement. You just need to declare the conformance to `Rankable` for both `Person` and `SportsMan`